# EmberJS: How to Handle Route with Dynamic Segment Returning an Array?

Tags: ember.js

**EDIT:**

I've gotten around this by upgrading to EmberJS RC4. This version doesn't automatically call the model hook on routes, which allows the following:

```
App.LiftsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({               
  setupController: function(controller, model) {          
    controller.set('content', App.Lift.find({
      county: model.county || model.id
    }));
  }
});
```

**EDIT END**

I'm attempting to add a route with a dynamic segment in EmberJS & Ember Data w/ RESTful Adapter which returns an array but I failing.

```
App.Router.map(function() {  
   this.route('lifts', { path: '/lifts/:county' });
});

App.LiftsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({           
  model: function(params) {                   
    return App.Lift.find(params.county);
  }
});

App.Lift = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  date: DS.attr('number'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  destination: DS.attr('string')
});
```

This is returning the following error:

Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key lifts but you have no mapping for it.

From JSON in the form {lifts: [{id: 1, name: "xyz", ...}, {id: 2, name: "abc", ...]}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Setting up a route with a single dynamic segment to return an array of objects**

You can still keep the same route structure:

```
this.route('lifts', { path: '/lifts/:county_ids' });
```

And then override the `model` hook to parse `params.county_ids` into a query string:

```
model: function(params) {
  ids  = parseQueryIds(params.county_ids) // you have to parse this in a format that your server will accept
  App.Lift.find({query: ids}) // returns an record array
}
```

This will preserve the url structure (if you go to `/lifts/1,2,3`, that url will be saved) but also returns an array of items.

**END EDIT**

This is happening because `App.Lift.find`, when passed a string, will try to query by id for a single object, but your response from the server is returning multiple objects (id 1, id 2, etc).

When you do `App.Lift.find(params.county)` (let's say `params.county` is "1"), Ember will make a `GET '/lifts/1'`.  But for whatever reason, your server is returning JSON with a key that has an array.

Can you check that

1. the GET request ember is making is indeed for a single id? If you're using chrome, check the network requests -- what is the resource that `App.Lift.find(params.county)` asks for?
2. that `params.county` is defined? If it's undefined, you'll be calling `App.Lift.find(undefined)`, which makes the GET to `/lifts`, and that might cause your server to return the array of objects.
3. that your server is responding to requests properly when a single id is requested?

Comment: You could try App.Lift.find(params.county_id)... you might currently be running into scenario 2 described in this answer

Comment: I am not looking for a single object to be return. /lifts/AB, /lifts/BB should return each lift by county. The server is returning the correct data, Ember just isn't parsing correctly. `params.county` is defined. A solution that half works for me is using `params.county` in a query string, but this results in the URL forming as `/lifts`, so we don't retain the URL structure.

Comment: @DavidT what do you expect params.county to be? When you pass a single string to ```find```, Ember will ATTEMPT to parse the response as a single object, which is why it's throwing an error, as your server is returning multiple. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SherwinYu I am trying to find each lift by county name. In order to retain the page on page reload, I am using /lifts/ABC where ABC is the county_id. Currently this doesn't seem to be possible as the URL structure /lift/:county expects a single object, even though I have the controller set as ArrayController and am returning an array server side.

Comment: @DavidT See my updated answer -- you're right that /lift/:county expects a single object, but you can parse the params and use ```find``` with a query, which will attempt to find many items on your server with a querystring ajax call. The user-facing URL structure is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

the error message occurs because the root id of your JSON object is plural, and should be singular. Your server should return:

```
{lift: [
        {id: 1, name: "xyz", ...},
        {id: 2, name: "abc", ...}
       ]
}
```

You will most likely subsequently run into the issue Sherwin describes, as find() for the RESTAdapter assumes a singleton to be returned.

Comment: Returning the key 'lift' results in a type error with: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver', as I think it expects lift to return a single object.

Comment: You could try "forcing" things by explicitly defining your `App.LiftsController` as an `Ember.ArrayController`.

Comment: It is setup as an ArrayController.